# How to access io.emit() from routes/index? on express 4.15

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

**bin/www.js**

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(client) {
console.log('Client connected...');
client.on('join', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
});

server.listen(port);
```

here i need to access or send messages or mongoose result via socket.io(i dont know it is possible or not?)

i need to send messages to client from `routes/index.js` page.
what i tried is,

```
module.exports.io = io; //(in `bin/www`)
```

and access thai io in index.js like this
    var io=require('../bin/www');

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
console.log('Client connected...');
client.on('join', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

but it thows some error

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
^
TypeError: io.on is not a function....
```

my need is ,
**I want to send dynamic results to client when a route get called or send some `mongoose` query results to client using `socket.io`** is it possible?

**on express 4.15 `var server = http.createServer(app);` is on bin/www.js**

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

    // view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
req.headers['if-none-match'] = 'no-match-for-this';
next();
});*/



//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
maxAge: '30d',
setHeaders: function (res, path) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=14770')
}
}));

console.log("PATH"+path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.io = require('socket.io')();
app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
// do whatever you want
});

const userRoute = require('./routes/index')(app.io);
app.use('/', userRoute);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
    });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

Error after update the code given by Ashish

```
PATHC:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\public
```

C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
             ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at
```

C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:14
    at next (C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:210:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Object. (C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\app.js:46:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\bin\www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

Comment: heii no bro.. i am not doing create server on app.js it is on www.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have generated the app using express generator which creates app.js and bin/www files, There is a circular dependency issue to use io object inside routes. Here's what you can do,

Inside app.js

```
app.io = require('socket.io')(); // initialize io, attach server in www
// use socket events here
app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
   // do whatever you want
})

// you can pass app.io inside the router and emit messages inside route.
const userRoute = require('./routes/user')(app.io);
app.use('/users', userRoute);
```

Inside bin/www

```
var io = app.io;  
var server = http.createServer(app);  
io.attach(server);
```

Now here's how router looks like, user.js

```
module.exports = function(io){
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
        io.emit("message", "your message");
        res.send();
    })
    // edited
    return router;
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach. :)

Comment: return fn.apply(this, arguments);
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at .... at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ADSS\Desktop\PrintAdmin\app.js:45:44)  error !!!

Comment: Can you please share your app.js file, so that I can run it and see.

Comment: bro i updated it please check

Comment: have you returned the router from index router function, I updated the code

Comment: no bro, i wil update the error

Comment: Your app.js file is running without any error. I got this log, PATH/home/ashish/work/github_contrib/demo-socket-io/public.

Make sure to check if you are returning the router from the exported function, as mentioned in the answer. And avoid duplicated require for index at start of the file. :)

Comment: no bro still iam getting a type error on app.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158486/discussion-between-anonymousobject-and-ashish-prajapati).

Comment: Awesome, that worked for me. Thanks @AshishPrajapati

Answer (score 0):

Note: I havent practically tried it yet.

But Can u try this pattern instead?

In www.js

```
 module.exports = function(io) {

  io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');
    client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
}
```

In index.js

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io')(server);

require('./wwww.js)(io);
```

Comment: bro var server = http.createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io')(server); is defined in www.js then how can i re define it on index.js?

Comment: You dont; Think of require as a form of copy - paste;
In this case; whatever is inside module.exports of www.js is now pasted inside index.js